# Missing grant type error with x-www-form-urlencoded in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, x-www-form-urlencoded

Hi this is the first time that I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I need to get a token, and when I submit a request with Alamofire I am getting this error:

> { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing grant
> type" }

here is a screenshot of my postman settings
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11fu3.png)

and here are the headers and parameters

```
 header["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 header["Accept"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

 params["client_id"] = "m"
 params["client_secret"] = "a4dc4eed"
 params["username"] = "m"
 params["password"] = "m"
 params["grant_type"] = "password"
 params["scope"] = "openid"
```

Comment: And how do you make your call? You said in header that you'll send parameters as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so did you really used that formatting? Without the Alamofire code, it's hard to tell what you did wrong...

Comment: @Larme what is the formatting to send the parameter as urlencoded ? because all i know to sent as json like params["grant_type"] = "password"

Comment: What's your Alamofire call code?